# How do I read this 'ip r' output?

Tags: debian, networking, virtualbox

This is a Debian in a virtual machine with two bridged network adapters configured. I am trying to understand what is the current routing state, so that I can modify it to use both 'network cards'.

```
$ traceroute abv.bg
traceroute to abv.bg (194.153.145.104), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.17.100.1 (10.17.100.1)  5.207 ms  5.184 ms  5.177 ms
 2  79.140.126.225 (79.140.126.225)  6.462 ms  6.458 ms  10.152 ms
 3  212.91.225.214 (212.91.225.214)  42.456 ms  45.608 ms  49.076 ms
   ...

$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2d:5d:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.17.101.246/22 brd 10.17.103.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe2d:5d3d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:25:8e:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip r
default via 10.17.100.1 dev enp0s3 
10.17.100.0/22 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.17.101.246 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000
```

My understanding is that (numbers refer to lines in the output of `ip r`):

1. All packets, that are directed to a network which we are not part of, are forwarded via device enp0s3 to the gateway, 10.17.100.1, which is a part of the VirtualBox program.
2. All packets, directed to the 10.17.100.0/22 network are assigned source ip 10.17.101.246 and sent directly to the ip they are meant for. If that ip exists, it is again part of VirtualBox, running on the host.
3. some weird `zeroconf` thing, which for some reason I don't see on my other Debian machine.

And finally: when I bring up enp0s8, all those routes should remain unchanged, ane only a new route should be added.

My question is **where are the errors of my understanding**.

Comment: You are basically correct, except that when you bring up `enp0s8` (depending on how you bring it up), you may get more routes, e.g. if it receives DHCP information. Also, an IP in 10.17.100.0/22 may or may not be "part of virtualbox", depending on how virtualbox is configured. Why do you think there are errors in your understanding?